# C# dynamic linq, where clause for list (nested) property

Tags: c#, linq

Using Dynamic Linq 3.5 library, I am trying to dynamically filter a list of objects like this:

```
public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}


public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
public class Products :
    SortableBindingList<Product>
    ,ITypedList 
    //,IEnumerable
    //,IQueryable
{
..... // irrelevant, just a list
}


Products prods = new Products{
            new Product { 
                Name = "abc", 
                Rating = 3, 
                Fields = new List<Field>{
                    new Field { Name = "One", Value = "One_value" },
                    new Field { Name = "Two", Value = "Two_value" }
                }
            },
            new Product { 
                Name = "def", 
                Rating = 4, 
                Fields = new List<Field>{
                    new Field { Name = "Three", Value = "Three_value" },
                    new Field { Name = "Four", Value = 123 },
                    new Field { Name = "Two", Value = "Also Two value" }
                }
            },
            new Product { 
                Name = "ghy", 
                Rating = 4, 
                Fields = new List<Field>{
                    new Field { Name = "Three", Value = "Three_value" },
                    new Field { Name = "Four", Value = 12 },
                    new Field { Name = "Two", Value = "12" }
                }
            },
            new Product { 
                Name = "ghy", 
                Rating = 4, 
                Fields = new List<Field>{
                    new Field { Name = "Three", Value = "Three_value" },
                    new Field { Name = "Four", Value = 9 },
                    new Field { Name = "Two", Value = "123" }
                }
            },
            new Product { 
                Name = "ghy", 
                Rating = 4, 
                Fields = new List<Field>{
                    new Field { Name = "Three", Value = "Three_value" },
                    new Field{ Name = "Four", Value = 22 },
                    new Field { Name = "Two", Value = "22" },
                    new Field { Name = "Five", Value = "Five value" }
                }
            },
        };
```

Now using the filter that is working

```
var queryable = prods.AsQueryable();
var test = queryable.Where("Name.Contains(\"abc\") && Fields[0].Name.StartsWith(\"One\")").ToProducts();

dgv.DataSource = test;
```

The problem is that Fields is a list of objects and I need to filter also by their Name and Value.

I just can't figure out how to refer nested properties in filter syntax by the value, not using Field[0].

```
    var queryable = prods.AsQueryable();

    var test = queryable.Where("Name.Contains(\"139\").Where(Field.Name ==\"One\").Any()").ToProducts(); // not working
```

Thank you!

Comment: Something like: `queryable.Where(n => n.Name.Contains("139")).Where(n => n.Name.Field.StartsWith("One")).ToProducts()` ..?

Comment: No property or field 'n' exists in type 'Product'

Comment: Don't know about dynamic linq, but how about "Fields.Any(n => n.Name == \"Three\")"

Comment: @Christoph Lütjen thank you, is working.